# Is the magnetic dipole moment in charged particles the more survivable property than the electric charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, charge, neutron-stars

After asking about [Which of the properties of particles are intrinsic properties and why?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234213/which-of-the-properties-of-particles-are-intrinsic-properties-and-why) it was commented "Charge, spin, lepton number, baryon number definitely. Mass maybe." and "is magnetic dipole moment really a separate property ?" What I'm wondering now is, that it seems to be that the magnetic dipole moment does not vanish in extreme situation whereas the electric charge gets weaker in bounded to the nucleus state by [Screening effect](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/235072/46708).

This seems to happen not only inside the atom but also in the other extreme, the neutron stars. The charge of the electrons and the protons merge but the magnetic dipole moments don't go away. And the intrinsic spin also does not disappear and perhaps should not disappear because this two properties are related to each other. So perhaps in extrem situations the magnetic dipole moment of charged particles is the more stable property than the electric charge?

Comment: You've misunderstood what is going on in the screening effect. The charge of the state doesn't change.

Comment: Hi, you asked me to look at this interesting question in another thread, and I would like to delve further into it, but from your profile it looks like you yourself are an experienced researcher, and so I am not sure that I am qualified to tell you anything you haven't already thought of, seeing as I am currently only at PhD level. I like that you share your question here, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no more than one comment I'll explain why I asked this question. Getting **any** answer from the community I will accept this answer.

The electric charge seems to be an intrinsic property of charged particles. This was clear to me too as long as I don't get the idea [About the distribution of electrons magnetic dipole moments in atoms](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler/Papers). There is explained that for Noble gases it is possible to arrange the dipole moments of the involved electrons in a symmetric way. Furthermore the shells with 2 (He), 8 (Ne) and 8(Ar) electrons are the only possible numbers to arrange the dipole moments symmetrical.

Never the screening effect was associated with the loss of electric charge inside atoms. On the other side the electric charge is conserved only pairwise. A proton and an electron (plus an antineutrino) could be merged into a neutron. In Neutron stars the electric charges get lost, but the magnetic properties still alive. In my elaboration about [Complex one-dimensional structures of space](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler/Papers) it was explained (long before the distribution of magnetic moments in atoms was elaborated) how the electric charges of proton and electron get lost partially. Furthermore it was explained how the electric charge is shielded in the case of relativistic velocities.